# How to resort components after rendering theme

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

lets say I have an array (of places in the map) that I loop through :

```
<div class="row" v-for="place in places">
        <place :place="place" v-if="place.distance"></place>
</div>
```

after the components are rendered i the page. the array get updated so I want to rearrange my components in my page after the array is updated.
is there a way to do that or to just stop components until the array is updated (I calling for google's geolocalisation ) and then render them in the right order (ordering by distance between locations)

Comment: That should work just like it is. If it doesn't, show the way you update the array.

Comment: So if I triggered any function that can mutate an array Vuejs will update automatically everything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented out, you don't need to do anything for this, vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also trigger view updates as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection). The wrapped methods are:

- push()
- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

You can see the working demo here how rearrangement happening [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/y4g8zt96/).

Sample JS Code:

```
Vue.component('comp2', {
  props: ['title'],
  template: '#comp2'
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    compArray: ['comp1', 'comp2', 'comp3']
  },
  methods: {
    resuffle: function() {
       this.compArray.splice(0,1)
       this.compArray.push(this.compArray[0])
    }
  },
})
```

Relevant HTML:

```
  <div v-for="comp in compArray">
      <comp2 :title="comp">
  </div>
```